# For loops, await, and promises - Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to use a for loop to iterate through an array and perform an async function on each item.
I want this to happen in a sequential order and I don't want the next async function for the next item in the array to execute until the async function for the previous item has COMPLETED.

I am using await and promises to try to do this. However, I must be doing something wrong because the code does not seem to be working right.
I have done some reading on other posts; however, I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code that is seen below.

```
function asyncFunc(i)
{
  //Here I am updating my database which is the async part of this function
  db.collection("collection").doc("doc").update({
  })
  
  .then(function(){  
      let d = new Date();
      console.log(i + " async COMPLETED at: " + d.getTime());
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve;
      });
  });
}

async function doWork()
{
  var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
  for(const i of numbers)
  {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(i + " async CALLED at: " + d.getTime());
    await asyncFunc(i);
  }
}

doWork();
```

The output that I get on my console is:

```
1 async CALLED at: 1594674023549
2 async CALLED at: 1594674023556
3 async CALLED at: 1594674023556
4 async CALLED at: 1594674023557
1 async COMPLETED at: 1594674023852
2 async COMPLETED at: 1594674023943
3 async COMPLETED at: 1594674024033
4 async COMPLETED at: 1594674024140
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `await` keyword only works on Promises. You will have to return the Promise from `asyncFunc`

Comment: Ah I see the problem. How do I return a promise AFTER I update the doc in my database if I do not have access to the code of the update function?

Comment: That's not exactly how it works. See [Daniel Geffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4852290/daniel-geffen)'s answer below. He is correct.

Comment: You don't want to be asynchronous, but follow synchronously, then don't use `async` nor `await`, don't use `promises`!!

Answer (score 1):

You should return the promise in `asyncFunc` so that the `await` keyword will wait until it resolves. So change it to this:

```
function asyncFunc(i)
{
  //Here I am updating my database which is the async part of this function
  return db.collection("collection").doc("doc").update({
  })
  
  .then(function(){  
      let d = new Date();
      console.log(i + " async COMPLETED at: " + d.getTime());
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: After doing what you said, it seems as if the loop is only iterating through the first element of the array, not the rest. This is what I am getting on my console: "1 async CALLED at: 1594676417571" followed with "1 async COMPLETED at: 1594676417720".

Comment: If you haven't replaced the part in the inner promise, the problem probably is that you didn't call the `resolve` function to resolve the promise. I updated my answer.